# How to handle inheritance using SimpleXML framework?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, simple-framework

I'm currently using [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) framework to parse an XML file and I'm facing a recurrent issue.

The received XML can be either something like this:

```
<root>
   <B>
      ...
   </B>
</root>
```

or something like that:

```
<root>
   <C>
      ...
   </C>
</root>
```

And I want B and C to extend another class, say A.

The tidy way to do that with SimpleXML would be:

```
@Root(name="root")
class Root {

   @Element(name="B", required="false")
   private B b;

   @Element(name="C", required="false")
   private C c;
}

class B extends A {

}

class C extends A {

}
```

I know I can do something I found in SimpleXML documentation, changing my XML format:

```
<root>
   <A class="example.B">     // or "example.C"
      ...
   </A>
</root>
```

and then my Java classes:

```
@Root(name="root")
class Root {

   @Element(name="A")
   private A a;
}

class B extends A {

}

class C extends A {

}
```

I'd really love to use this solution but I'm not sure at all if I want to go through the process of change the XML on the client side before parsing it. The problem is it can't be done on the server side as I have no control on it.

So my questions are:

**Is this the only solution I have?**

**In this case, do you guys know if there is a fast solution to change my xml file on the client side?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure how to make inheritance but I found a solution using interfaces (which is ok in my case)

The trick is to use:

```
@Root(name="root")
class Root {

   @ElementUnion({
       @Element(name="B", type=B.class),
       @Element(name="C", type=C.class)
   })
   private A a;
}

interface A {

}

class B implements A {

}

class C implements A {

}
```

It would be nice if we could do the same with inheritance though.

UPDATE: inheritance is available using `@ElementUnion`. Although it's not specified in the doc, this works too:

```
@Root(name="root")
class Root {

   @ElementUnion({
       @Element(name="B", type=B.class),
       @Element(name="C", type=C.class)
   })
   private A a;
}

class A {

}

class B extends A {

}

class C extends A {

}
```